# Having a # (hash-sign) in \href in a longtabu cell

Tags: hyperref, tabu, longtabu

I have a longtabu table (externally generated) with in one of the cells a `href` with an `url` that contains a has sign. When compiling this with pdflatex I get:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
                   c
l.18 \end{longtabu}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu}spread 0pt [c]{*{2}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
{ test  }&{ URL   }\\\cline{1-2}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
{ test  }&{ URL   }\\\cline{1-2}
\endhead
test & \href{http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdpage}{\texttt{ URL with hash}}   \\\cline{1-2}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

In the documentation of the `hyperref` package I found with the `\href` command in the paragraph '4 Additional user macros':

> `\href[options]{URL}{text}` The text is made a hyperlink to the URL;
>   this must be a full URL (relative to the base URL, if that is
>   defined). The special characters `#` and `~` do not need to be escaped in
>   any way.

So looks like some interaction between the `href` and `longtabu`.

I can overcome the problem by escaping the `#`-hash sign in the `url`:

```
\href{http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html\#cmdpage}
```

but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

- Is my way the correct way?
- is this a wrong usage of the `\href` in the `longtabu` from my side?
- is this a bug ?

Comment: @egreg You edited the escape with a backquote whilst I intended a backslash. Was you edit there necessary / didn't my backslash  show or was this a solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the misprint, but it was better to make the line into a code line (indented by four spaces). And there was no backslash, but a backquote in the original.

Comment: Oops was already an error at my side ( :-( ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to escape `#`, you need to make it printable:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\catcode`#=12
\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt [c]{*{2}{|X[-1]}|}
\hline
test & URL \\ \cline{1-2}
\endfirsthead
\hline
test & URL \\ \cline{1-2}
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
test & \href{http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdpage}
            {\texttt{ URL with hash}}
\\
\cline{1-2}
\end{longtabu}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So either 1) use the escape or 2) make it printable. Is there ar reason that longtabu doesn't follow non-escaping rule from the `\href` command?

Comment: @albert `longtabu` reads the table body as the argument to a command, so the self-escaping mechanism of `\href` cannot work.

Comment: Does this also apply to other commands / environments?

Comment: @albert To `tabularx`, for instance, or the alignment environments of `amsmath`.