# Double "#" (hash) char when using expl3 string

Tags: expl3, strings, catcodes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\catcode`#=11
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#}
\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_str
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpb_str {#}
\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpb_str
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The above code gives

```
The token list \l_tmpa_str contains the tokens:
>  # (the character #)
>  # (the character #).
<recently read> }

l.7 \tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_str

?
The token list \l_tmpb_str contains the tokens:
>  # (the character #).
<recently read> }

l.9 \tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpb_str

?
```

Why there are two `#` in `\l_tmpa_str` but only one in `\l_tmpb_str`?

Comment: See also [macros - Prevent hash doubling with \message - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520388/prevent-hash-doubling-with-message)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget that in `\ExplSyntaxOn` a line end doesn't make a space, so your input is essentially the same as:

```latex
\catcode`#=11\str_set:Nn\l_tmpa_str{#}
```

then TeX, looking for a termination to the integer `11`, expands `\str_set:Nn` which grabs `#6`, freezing its catcode, and then it gets doubled by `\tl_to_str:n` (in `\str_set:Nn`), and then `\tl_analysis_show:N` sees `#12#12`. Using the proper `expl3` function for changing catcodes solves the problem (or adding a `~` at the end of the line):

```latex
\char_set_catcode_letter:N \#
% \catcode`\#=11~
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#}
\tl_analysis_show:N \l_tmpa_str
```

Comment: Great explanation! It's interesting to note that the `~` is not ignored at the end of a line, but would be removed as part of tokenizing a control word as in  `\cs_new:Npn \foo { a \c_empty_tl ~ b }` (`\cs_show:N \foo` would print `\foo=\long macro:->a\c_empty_tl b.`).

Comment: @frougon That's right. Though it's not ignored at the end of _that_ line because the space follows a character token. If the line ended with a control sequence token, the `~` would be ignored as well.

Comment: (a character token with catcode 12). Of course, but this would be due to tokenizing the control *word*, not to the end of the line. Unless I'm saying crap. :-)

Comment: @frougon No, you are correct! That was be being sloppy when stating rules (I probably learned this from The TeXbook, with Knuth always telling half-truths :-)

Comment: Yup, formulating such rules perfectly precisely is very difficult. Thanks!