# LaTeX3: LaTeX doubles the number of hashes when storing them in string

Tags: latex3

I have some code that convert some macros to a string to write, but unfortunately when a character # is given as input it is turned into ##. I tried to play with catcodes, but seems like it is not effective:

The following code shows:

```
Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem ##
```

instead of

```
Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem #
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineString}{m}{
  \char_set_catcode_letter:N \#
  \str_set:Nn \l_test_str {#1}
  % My failed other try:
  % \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_test_str {\char_set_catcode_letter:N \#}{#1}
  % \tl_to_str:n \l_test_str
w}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showString}{}{
  \show\l_test_str
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\defineString{Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem #}
\showString

\end{document}
```

Comment: Every solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520388/prevent-hash-doubling-with-message also works here. See if you can adapt them.

Comment: this is unrelated to latex3, it is a feature of the primitive `\show` command you are using

Comment: Thanks! @DavidCarlisle Well, apparently any command I run on this string see two hashes. \show, but also when I write it to a file, or if I print it verbatim in the file… But egreg’s answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\char_set_catcode_letter:N` does nothing useful; actually it does harm, because from the first usage of your `\defineString` command, `#` will become category code 11 (respecting grouping).

You want to replace the doubled hashes with single ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineString}{m}
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_test_str {#1}
  \str_replace_all:Nnx \l_test_str { ## } { \c_hash_str }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showString}{}{
  \str_show:N \l_test_str
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\defineString{Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem #}
\showString

\end{document}
```

You get

```
> \l_test_str=Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem #.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking of doing that but I thought it would be an ugly fix (so I wrote some other tricks in my other answer, but I trust you more on the fact that your solution is cleaner ^^).

Comment: Btw, here is a followup question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695497/pgf-key-style-with-no-argument-or-how-to-avoid-escaping-hashes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @user202729, I came up with this more "robust" (I hope?) definition:

```
\cs_set:Nn \str_set_hash_robust:Nn {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_test_str { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP\# } { \cO\# } \l_test_str
  \tl_to_str:N {#1}
}
```

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695432/latex3-latex-doubles-the-number-of-hashes-when-storing-them-in-string/695460#695460
\cs_set:Nn \str_set_hash_robust:Nn {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_test_str { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP\# } { \cO\# } \l_test_str
  \tl_to_str:N {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineString}{m}{
  \str_set_hash_robust:Nn \l_test_str {#1} 
  % \char_set_catcode_letter:N \#
  % \str_set:Nn \l_test_str {#1}
  % My failed other try:
  % \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_test_str {\char_set_catcode_letter:N \#}{#1}
  % \tl_to_str:n \l_test_str
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showString}{}{
  \show \l_test_str
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\defineString{Hey \notexistingbutnoproblem #}
\showString

\pgfkeys{
  test/.style={
    /utils/exec={% Goal 2: can I avoid escaping the # here?
      \defineString{Foo \notexistingbutnoproblem ##}
      \showString
    }
  },
  test
}


\end{document}
```